# droping duplicates in pandas based on several values be the same

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I want to drop all rows of a pandas dataframe when a subset of columns has the same values.
It could be done with e.g., `itterrow()` going through each line and getting the index of each row which fullfills it.
However, is there a more pythonic/pandas way?

Example:
we have a dataframe with columns `"name", "age", "school", "grade", "sex"`
Now I want to remove all duplicates where, e.g., `"age","school"` and `"grade"` is the same for the specific column. Keeping e.g., the first.

so:

```
Tom, 17, WestHigh, 5.0, M
Ray, 14, NorthLow, 2.1, F
Ane, 17, WestHigh, 5.0, F
```

should result in

```
Tom, 17, WestHigh, 5.0, M
Ray, 14, NorthLow, 2.1, F
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: it seems you already have the answer, what else do you expect?

Comment: The answer came to me a second after posting. So I thought I share it. :-) Sometimes we just have to formulate the question in clear words.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=["age", "school", "grade"], keep="first")
```